# SQL Delete duplicates if the date matches

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a simple table:

```
Create Table data
( 
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Price Int,             
    Date date,
    Tmstmp date
)
```

Populating Table with values:

```
INSERT INTO data (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Price, date, Tmstmp)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Snow', 100, '2020-04-08', '2020-01-01 10:34:09.000');
INSERT INTO data (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Price, date, Tmstmp)
VALUES (2, 'Tony', 'Stark', 100, '2020-05-10', '2020-01-01 11:34:09.000');
INSERT INTO data (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Price, date, Tmstmp)
VALUES (3, 'Tony', 'Stark', 120, '2021-12-11', '2020-01-01 12:34:09.000');
INSERT INTO data (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, Price, date, Tmstmp)
VALUES (4, 'Tony', 'Stark', 125, '2021-12-11', '2020-01-01 13:34:09.000');
```

[image]

The goal is to preserve only the values with the latest date. But only if the date is duplicated.
So that Tony Stark will have 2 records with 2 dates. The duplicated row with the same date `2021-12-11` and the oldest timestamp will be deleted.

So The records will look like this:

[image]

I tried self join on tables but couldn't make it work. Tried also using ROW_NUMBER but im confused how the Partition By works. Any help to achieve my goal will be very much appreciated.

What I tried to do but havent been successful

```
DELETE FROM data d1
INNER JOIN data d2
ON d1.personID = d2.personID
AND d1.Date = d2.Date
WHERE d1.Tmstmp < d2.Tmstmp
```

Comment: Please TAG your specific database

Comment: I actually used sqliteonline.com, so the database is irrelevant

Comment: How so? it looks like this supports several different RDBMS inc mysql, Postgres and Sql Server, so just how is it irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most modern RDBMS you can use an *updatable CTE* in conjunction with *row number*

```
with d as (
    select *,
      Row_Number() over(partition by firstname, lastname, date order by Tmstmp desc) rn
    from data
)
delete from d
where rn>1
```

Comment: Got error : ```no such table: d``` Maybe because im using website instead of ssms? Thanks for help

Comment: Sounds like the engine you've selected on sqliteonline.com doesn't support CTEs in this context, if I choose for example to use MS SQL, it works fine. See [example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0fdf2060ce164a65bce42740fe67a59)

Comment: By the way what is the the meaning of using only ```firstname, lastname and date``` in ```partition by``` ? I've read about it but can't quite understand its meaning.

Comment: The partition is essentially how the rows are grouped, you want to consider how the timestamp varies for each group of rows that are common on those 3 columns.

Comment: So if Tony Stark records had all the same ```personID's``` then should I also put it in the ```partition by``` clause?

Comment: Yes, but if you did that with them being different like they are, each row becomes its own group and you're no better off.